# How can you reliably get the Digest / Hash / Fingerprint of a file you are downloading via http(s) before you actually download it?

Tags: https, hash, http-headers, md5

Take the following url:

`https://i.imgur.com/oEdf6Rl.png`

When I do a request for it:

```
Connection
keep-alive

Content-Length
44374

Last-Modified
Sun, 21 Feb 2021 15:14:36 GMT

ETag
"83c16cca4ee371145485130383104315"

Content-Type
image/png

cache-control
public, max-age=31536000

Accept-Ranges
bytes

Date
Thu, 25 Feb 2021 18:33:52 GMT

Age
357546

X-Served-By
cache-bwi5147-BWI, cache-sea4455-SEA

X-Cache
HIT, HIT

X-Cache-Hits
1, 1

X-Timer
S1614278033.761056,VS0,VE1

Strict-Transport-Security
max-age=300

Access-Control-Allow-Methods
GET, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin
*

Server
cat factory 1.0

X-Content-Type-Options
nosniff

NoError
Unknown error
```

I don't see any hash there. I've read that you can request optional hashes with headers such as `Content-MD5` ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1864 ) and `Want-Digest` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Want-Digest << I have yet to find a single file however that supports this header )

- What does not make sense to me is that when you download that image, and it does not provide a hash like an `md5`, how is it verifying that what I received was in fact what was sent?
- If it is verifying with a hash, why are there all these random optional headers where you can request hashes?
- I need to know if there is a reliable way to get file's fingerprint/hash/digest before actually downloading it. If not; is there a "most" reliable method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does not make sense to me is that when you download that image, and it does not provide a hash like an md5, how is it verifying that what I received was in fact what was sent?

Most HTTP servers don't support providing a digest.  While some do, it is very uncommon.  If you're using HTTPS, then TLS provides integrity guarantees that the data is intact and has not been tampered with due to either an HMAC value (a keyed hash) or an AEAD encryption algorithm (which is essentially encryption and a keyed hash all in one).  Assuming the connection is properly terminated and both sides speak the protocol correctly and verify the integrity properly, you can be sure the data sent by the other end of the connection is intact.

> If it is verifying with a hash, why are there all these random optional headers where you can request hashes?

These header values are most useful when the digest is precomputed and fixed and the digest is used to detect unintentional problems between the system which created it and the server serving it.  For example, it could be used to detect whether a CDN has a programming bug that causes it to unexpectedly to truncate data.

They could also be used in a HEAD request to find out the digest of an object without sending the entire object.  For example, if you're using HTTPS and want to collect the digest for future use without downloading the data, then those headers could be useful.  Note that since MD5 is completely insecure and isn't used by responsible parties, the `Content-MD5` header is completely useless and wouldn't provide any useful information, although the `Digest` header with one of the SHA-256 or SHA-512 values certainly could.

> I need to know if there is a reliable way to get file's fingerprint/hash/digest before actually downloading it. If not; is there a "most" reliable method?

Since most sites don't offer the `Digest` header, you can't use it most places.  If your goal is to do something like verify the integrity of software, various distributors provide hashes, signatures, or both, although that depends on the project.  If you just want to be sure that the data you received isn't tampered with, use HTTPS.  If you just want to know the hash of the contents located at an arbitrary URL, then unless the server supports the `Digest` header, you'll just have to download it to find out.

Answer (score 1):

> •   What does not make sense to me is that when you download that image, and it does not provide a hash like an md5, how is it verifying that what I received was in fact what was sent?

It doesn’t. Though the fact it’s over HTTPS gives certain guarantees that the message has not be altered.

> •   If it is verifying with a hash, why are there all these random optional headers where you can request hashes?

Those are additional ones. Though it should be noted that RFC 1884 is for MIME messages (i.e. Email attachments) not HTTP requests. For Content-MD5 for HTTP this was obsoleted and now the `Want-Digest`/`Digest` method is the one to use.

But why do you need it at all if HTTPS guarantees the message has not been tampered with? The [draft spec covers this](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-digest-headers-04.html):

> *“However, there are cases where relying on this alone is insufficient. An HTTP-level integrity mechanism that operates independent of transfer can be used to detect programming errors and/or corruption of data at rest, be used across multiple hops in order to provide end-to-end integrity guarantees, aid fault diagnosis across hops and system boundaries, and can be used to validate integrity when reconstructing a resource fetched using different HTTP connections.”*

> •   I need to know if there is a reliable way to get file's fingerprint/hash/digest before actually downloading it. If not; is there a "most" reliable method?

The Digest header is rarely supported IMHO so the most reliable way is to download a hash separately. Many software download pages ([for example Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)) make these available as separate download links to the binaries. Though those are to ensure ultimate end download integrity rather than the HTTP part.

To be honest HTTPS solves most of the need of digests in the for the transport layer security, which is the me reason why you see Digest being used much, unless building a specialised app that wants to send this separately.